# Webservice using CXF and Spring 3 webserviceTemplate gets error on Jboss 5 due to Soap Message Factory

Tags: java, spring, soap, jboss, cxf

Using this configuration (which works fine in Tomcat) for initializing my webserviceTemplate:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean class="com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPMessageFactory1_2Impl"/>
    </property>
</bean>   
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
   <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I get this stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPMessageFactory1_2Impl' to required type 'javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory' for property 'messageFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.SOAPMessageFactory1_2Impl] to required type [javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory] for property 'messageFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I am unable to figure out the resolution, any ideas?

Comment: My guess, you have classloading issues. Make sure that you don't include any xml api jar files in your application and/or also make sure that in JBoss you use parent-last classloading (or whatever it is called nowadays in JBoss).

Comment: I am unable to make this work, however it turns out I can ditch the webserviceTemplate and just have cxf spring namespace (jaxws:client) declare my webservice client. This in turn does not require me to declare any message factory.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and finally noticed that the exception message suggested that a property "messageFactory" could not be set on the SaajSoapMessageFactory. This is confusing, because "messageFactory" is also the name of the bean being created as SaajSoapMessageFactory. Spring was failing to set the messageFactory property of SaajSoapMessageFactory to the same SaajSoapMessageFactory bean.

I found two solutions:

- My  element included default-autowire="byName". By removing
  this, the issue disappeared.
- Without removing the default-autowire attribute, I explicitly set the messageFactory property to null. This is a bit awkward but also
  appears to work:

```
    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
         <property name="soapVersion">
             <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
         </property>
         <property name="messageFactory">
             <null />
         </property>
     </bean>
```